# How can I get an object by id using json-server?

Tags: javascript, express, json-server, module.exports

I'm trying to fetch an object by id using json-server.
When I return just one variable(one json) in module.exports of database file, it works. But, if I return an object of multiple variables, i get a 404.

The resources are:
http://localhost:3000/users
http://localhost:3000/admins

GET users returns 200 in both cases.
GET admins returns 200 in both cases.
But GET users/1234 returns 404 when trying to return multiple json files.

The database file db.js:

```
var users  = require('./users.json');
var admins = require('./admins.json');

module.exports = function() {
return {
    users  : users,
    admins : admins
 } ; // With this 'GET users' or 'GET admins' works, but 'GET users/1234' don't
 // return users; // With this return, it works GET users, GET admins and GET users/1234 
}
```

The json file users.json:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "name": "Andrew Owen",
            "age": 26,
            "eyeColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "name": "Susan prueba",
            "age": 45,
            "eyeColor": "hazel"
        }
     ]
}
```

command: json-server --watch db.js

Comment: It looks like you have issues with routing.

Comment: Your *users.json* file should contain only an array, not a `{ "users": … }` object

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the id to the fetch function to get the user detail of particular id :

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users?id=${val}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually id is created by default by the json server if you wont provided and it gives default sequential values from 1,2,3,4...

For me, it worked as id is provided by json-server when I fetched GET users/1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).